# Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I want to add Facebook share button to my site. But when I use the code given by Facebook, it doesn't show any FB logo image in button style & also doesn't count any share.  Please help me figure out a better code.

Currently, I'm using:

```
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to say?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to add Facebook share button would be to visit  http://www.facebook.com/share_partners.php and copy the code and paste it in your  webpage after replacing the text "url" with the actual URL of the page you want to  share. If it is dynamic content, you can use the variable or object name.

```
 <script>
function fbs_click(){
u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false;
}
</script>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank"> <img src= "http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?8:26981" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official documentation: [Facebook For Developers: Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/).

If you merely click the "Get Code" option on the [Facebook Share Button Configurator & Generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/#configurator), you'll see that the URL generated is rather simple:

> https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={yourURLhere}

At least it seems that way to me:

[image]